# An error occurred: Failed to process your item

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

Im trying to upload app to chrome webstore using developer dashboard. After upload ZIP file im getting this error

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

The field permissions.http://webhvd.dincloud.com/ is not allowed in manifest.
The field content_scripts is not allowed in manifest.
```

I've already tested the app using chrome developer mode and it's working fine. No errors. Here's the manifest file:

```
{
    "app": {
    "launch": {
        "local_path": "main.html"
    }
},
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jsfile.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*.example.com/*" ]
} ],
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' http://*.examplecom; style-src 'self' http://sub.example.com; img-src 'self' http://*.example.com; font-src *; connect-src 'self' http://sub.example.com ",
"default_locale": "en",
"description": "__MSG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION__",
"icons": {
    "128": "icon128.webp",
    "16": "icon16.webp",
    "48": "icon48.webp"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "__MSG_PRODUCT_NAME__",
"permissions": [ "http://sub.example.com/", "storage", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite" ],
"version": "1.2"
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/restricting-extension-apis-in-legacy.html

Comment: thnx for reply. The blog says "Beginning this week, you won’t be able to publish legacy packaged apps in the Chrome Web Store that request any of the following permissions:". If permissions tag not allowed in manifest then how can i allow some url permissions, so that i can post and request data from that url. Without adding url in permissios tab i get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

Comment: @AaqibIqbal, I also encountered this now. Have you had any luck on a fix for this?

Comment: @fedmich im still stuck with this problem. I've also posted this to google groups but hasn't got any reply yet. let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: ok, I'll post back here when I've got a solution for us.

Comment: I am getting a error kinda similar "An error occurred: Failed to process your item. manifest.json:37:1: unknown syntax error." Were you able to fix yours?

Comment: not yet. still stuck at "An error occured".

Comment: Can you post your manifest somewhere?

Comment: I am able to solve the problem from server side. I removed the permissions entries (that was causing the problems) from apps' manifest file and while returning the json data from server side i returned a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem. I removed all the comments from my manifest file and that solved it for me. You may want to double check that the manifest you are uploading is comment free.

Comment: This certainly did. I had the comment in the manifest.json. no complaints for Microsoft, every developer (including me) fail to provide right error message back to the user.